# [Error: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information: No key table entry found matching

Tags: npm, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have been working on implementing SSO in a NodeJS application using an AD hosted on an azure VM. I am using [npm-kerberos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos) in my application. Here is how I have configured everything:

- I have created an SPN for the service
- Generated a keytab with that SPN
- Replicated keytab in my ubuntu server /etc/
- Installed kerberos client and configued krb5.conf accordingly

In my apllication I have installed kerberos npm:

- principalDetails method return HTTP/enpast.com@REALM.COM which is what I want.
- checkPassword also works all good.
- initializeServer fails using the SPN that I get from principalDetails.

Here is code:

```
const service = 'HTTP/enpast.com@REALM.COM'
kerberos.initializeServer(service, (err, data)=>{
      if (err) {
        console.log('Failed intialization---->', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Successfully initialized server', data);
      }
    });
```

Here is the error message I get:

> [Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: No key table entry found matching HTTP/enpast.com/realm.com@]

Any leads to the cause will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and to fix it I had to declare `service` this way:

```
const service = 'HTTP@enpast.com'
```

note where the '@' character is.

Answer (score -1):

The error log is self-explanatory. Double-check that you have the principal at the server's keytab: `klist -k path_to_keytabfile`

Comment: here is the output 
`Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5 HTTPS/enpast.com@SCREWSSO.EASTUS.CLOUDAPP.AZURE.COM
`

Comment: Notice that the principal is HTTPS. But the error specifies HTTP.

Comment: In Kerberos, HTTP and HTTPS specify the same service.  That's not the problem.

Comment: Then he should double-check his **realm** configuration. I assumed that `real.com` was a placeholder name to mask the real one. But given that Haris pubish the actual real, it seems to be a mismatch.